# No Product matches the given query

Tags: ajax, django

i was trying to delete an item using ajax
but encountered this problem

here are the models:

```
class LikeItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get_item(self , product):
        return self.all().filter(item=product)

class LikeItem(models.Model):
    like = models.ForeignKey("Like")
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True , blank=True )

    objects = LikeItemManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item.title

    def remove(self):
        return self.item.remove_from_like()




class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , null=True , blank=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Product,through=LikeItem)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True , auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False , auto_now=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def product(self):
        return "\n , ".join([p.title for p in self.items.all()])
```

here is the view which is a class based view

```
class LikeView(SingleObjectMixin , View):
    model = Like
    template_name = "likes/like.html"

    def get_object(self , *args , **kwargs):
        like_id = self.request.session.get("like_id")
        if like_id == None:
            like = Like()
            like.save()
            like_id = like.id
            self.request.session["like_id"] = like_id

        like = Like.objects.get(id=like_id)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            like.user = self.request.user
            like.save()

        return like

    def get(self, request , *args , **kwargs):
        like = self.get_object()
        item_id= request.GET.get("item") 
        delete_item = request.GET.get("delete")
        template = self.template_name
        context = {
        "object" : self.get_object()
        }

        if item_id:
            item_instance = get_object_or_404(Product , id=item_id)
            like_item = LikeItem.objects.get_or_create(like=like , item=item_instance)[0]
            if delete_item:
                like_item.delete()
            else:
                like_item.save()


        return render(request , template , context)
```

here is my template :

```
<div class="like-info">
            <ul>
            <li class="like-info-pills">{{ item.item.get_title }}</li>
            <li class="like-info-pills">Size: {{ item }}</li>
            <li class="like-info-pills">Rs. {{ item.item.get_sales_price }}</li>
            <li class="like-info-pills">{{ item.item.description}}</li>
            <li class="text-center">
            <form method='GET' id= "removefrm">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "item" value="{{item.id}}">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "delete" value="True">
            <button type="submit" id="removebtn">remove</button>
            </form>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and here is the ajax function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#removebtn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $("#removefrm").serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", // "POST"
        url: "{% url 'like' %}",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("removebtn").innerHTML = 'removed';
            } 
            , 
        error: function(response, error) {
            // console.log(response)
            // console.log(error)
            alert("error");     }
    })
})

</script>
```

and i am getting this error

```
No Product matches the given query.
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/like/?item=35&delete=True
Raised by:  likes.views.LikeView
No Product matches the given query.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: if you have the ajax function being called when you click the button I don't think you need to add the url to the action atribute of the form.

Comment: Can you post more of the traceback? It should say which line is causing the error.

Comment: edited the traceback

Comment: removed action attribute

Comment: @jape i am not able to gather the line as no traceback is coming...stuck on the above error

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this line: `item_instance = get_object_or_404(Product , id=item_id)`

You're trying to get a `Product` instance, but your `get_object()` function is returning a `Like` instance.